# React: Send post request to server using the data with the state updated in useEffect

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

recently I encountered a problem, the code is as below:

```
const [data, setData] = useState("");


useEffect(()=>{
  axios.get("http://localhost:4000/getData")
.then(res => {
   setData(res.data); //res = {data: "xxx"}
}).catch(err => console.log(err);
  
  console.log(data);

  axios.post("http://localhost:4000/postData",{data: data}).then(res=>console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err);
},[]);
```

1. If I console.log the res in the get request, I can see the res and it is something I want.
2. But when I console.log the data updated by useState in the next line, it is still the initial state, but not the updated one.
3. In the postData route of server, the console.log of req.body.data is still the initial state.

So are there any ways to get the response, update state, and then send the post request with the updated state inside the useEffect hook every time?

Comment: Ok so you'll need to probably do some tutorials on sync vs. async code in Javascript, as well as Promise syntax and async/await syntax. You're treating the axios calls and their callbacks as if they're synchronous, it doesn't work like that. Someone could rewrite it for you so that it's correct, but you'll just face the problem again if you don't understand asynchronous code in Javascript and the correct syntaxes for these things

Answer (score 0):

So what you are having there is you are setting the wrong data, you are using **setData(data)** instead it should be **setData(res.data)**

```
const [data, setData] = useState("");

useEffect(()=>{
  axios.get("http://localhost:4000/getData").then(res => setData(res.data)).catch(err => console.log(err);
  
  console.log(data);

  axios.post("http://localhost:4000/postData",{data: data}).then(res=>console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err);
},[]);
```

**But if you want to use "data" this is how you can go about it:**

```
const [data, setData] = useState("");

useEffect(()=>{
  
  async function loadData(){
   
    const {data} = await axios.get(url);
    
    //Now in this case you can use 
    setData(data)

  }
  
  loadData();

  axios.post("http://localhost:4000/postData",{data: data}).then(res=>console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err);
},[]);
```

Comment: Don't think this will work, because the `data` variable is destructured with `const`, which means it's block scoped. So it won't exist outside the `loadData` function

Comment: Sorry for typo mistake, it is setData(res.data), i just want to know how can I pass the data in the post request

Comment: Hold on is the "data" in "Post" call the same as the one coming from "Get" call? If yes, then that can be accessed because we are setting state on "Get" call then post call I pick from state

Comment: @NtshemboHlongwane you mean putting the post request inside the get request.then() function?, yes it is the same "data" coming back from "get"

Comment: Accessing it via state "data" once that "Get" call is complete your state changes, and you can access state, and I believe you might want to add "data" as a dependancy

Comment: @auntR That could be another solution because on ```req.then``` you know that the data is in you disposal so you can pass it to "Post" call then continue with your logic

Comment: @NtshemboHlongwane Thanks so much for yr suggestion. But can I know more about add "data" as a dependancy?

Comment: So this will be a great  read for you to [understand when to add dependency in useEffect](https://reacttraining.com/blog/when-to-use-functions-in-hooks-dependency-array/)